# C compilation error : called object is not a function

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor, function-pointers

I have created a macro for initializing a structure with some data, including a callback function pointer because this code is extensively reused in my file. I am storing the function pointer so I can simply iterate over the structure without having to explicitly check the msg_id and call the corresponding handling function.

These lines of code are around line number 150 :

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    some_list        *child_list;
    void             *data;
    void             *msg_func;
    int              nesting_level;
    int              msg_id;
} my_struct_t;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#define MALLOC_STRUCT_WITH_BASIC_DATA(level, msg_id, data_arg)     \
    my_struct_t *new_child = NULL;                                 \
    MY_CALLOC(new_child, my_struct_t, 1, failure);                 \                                          
    LISTCREATE(new_child->child_list);                             \
    new_child->data = data_arg;                                    \                                                            
  
#define INIT_MY_STRUCT(level, msg_id, data_arg, child_func)        \
if (some_condition_on_data_arg_is_satisfied(data_arg)) {           \
    MALLOC_STRUCT_WITH_BASIC_DATA(level, msg_id);                  \
    new_child->msg_func = &child_func;                             \                                        
    (new_child->msg_func)(new_child, new_child->data);             \
}
```

There are about 100+ msg functions and the list will keep increasing in the future. Their declarations are around line 250 :

```
static void msg_function1(my_struct_t *st, data_type1 *ptr_data);
static void msg_function2(my_struct_t *st, data_type2 *ptr_data);
...
static void msg_functionn(my_struct_t *st, data_typen *ptr_data);
```

Finally, the macros are invoked around line number 580 and message handling functions are defined starting around line number 700.

I get a compilation error when the macro is encountered :
`my_file.c:586: error: called object ‘new_child->msg_func’ is not a function`

This is my first time using function pointers. I searched on stackoverflow and google and tried to eliminate possible causes, including ordering of function declaration and usage. Could someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong here? To note, I do not have permission to change the message handling functions' type to void * or something else.

Comment: And the compiler is correct. A generic `void *` pointer doesn't have any specific type, it's just a pointer and can point to anything. That you make it point to a function isn't something the compiler can know. You need to *type-cast* the pointer to the correct type before using it. You need to do this for any `void *` pointer, even when not pointing to a function.

Comment: I thought the function type is void itself so type-casting is not required here. Is that understanding incorrect?

Comment: `void *` is a generic pointer that can point to *anything*. It needs a cast to be usable. `void` when used as a return-type is different, and means that the function returns nothing.

Comment: declare it as `void             (*msg_func)();` - the you will have a function pointer. You can cast then to the correct one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `void *` does not have defined behavior for pointing to anything. The C standard defines its behavior for pointing to objects, when used correctly. It does not define conversions between pointers to object types and pointers to function types. To point to generic function types, one should use a pointer-to-function-type. The standard defines the behavior for converting between all pointer-to-function types; it is merely necessary to use a suitable type when actually calling the function.

Comment: @Panda142308: A function type cannot be `void`. The return type of a function can be `void`, but the type of function itself must be “function returning `void`” or “function taking `int` and `double` and returning `void`”, or some such. `void *` is not a function type or a pointer to a function type. `void (*)()` is a pointer to a function taking unspecified parameters and returning `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a function pointer not an "ordinary" void pointer in your structure.

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    some_list        *child_list;
    void             *data;
    void             (*msg_func)(my_struct_t *, void *);
    int              nesting_level;
    int              msg_id;
} my_struct_t;
```

Ten message functions should convert the void pointer to the correct object pointer

```
static void msg_function2(my_struct_t *st, void *vData)
{
    data_type2 *ptr_data = vData;
    /* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @0___________ . I had a query based on your answer. I wish to use the function pointer to call one of the many msg functions (as shown in the question with msg_function1, 2..n ). Do I need to then have all these type-casted function pointers for each msg function, and should I put that in my struct as a union?

There are about 100+ msg functions and the list will keep increasing in the future.

Comment: @Panda142308: If all your message functions have one type, use that type for the pointer to them in the structure. If they have different types, this could be managed by using one type for them in the structure and using casts when calling them. However, the example you show shows the functions differ only in the type of data the second parameter points to. In that case, the usual solution is to make them all have a parameter of `void *`, so all the functions have type `void foo(my_struct_t *, void *)`.

Comment: @Panda142308 you need only one pointer type. Message function handling functions have to be written by the programmer so what is the problem in adding one line of code?